# Storing a whole Array into a Session variable

Tags: vb.net

Hei fellow Stackoverflowers,

I got a little problem with Session variables in VB.Net. I need to store a Array into a Session variable so that I can get the values back in another .aspx.vb. But somehow it won't work. If i try to read the values in the other page it's empty.

Here is my code for the checkboxes:

```
    Private Sub chdBoxes()

    Dim data()
    Dim datacount As Integer
    datacount = 0

    ReDim data(GridView1.Rows.Count)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("check1"), CheckBox)
            If chkRow.Checked Then
                Dim storeid As Integer = row.Cells(1).Text
                data(datacount) = storeid
                datacount = datacount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Session("rows") = GridView1.Rows.Count
    Session("id") = data
End Sub
```

I appreciate every feedback and thank you for helping me out.

Greetings Soulrox

Comment: Why don't you use a `List(Of Integer)` instead of that array? That's the appropriate collection type if you need to add items.

Comment: If I try to read the values in the other aspx.vb file it is empty :/

Comment: You should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). If you make the corrections it points out for you, it will help to make your program more predictable. And in this case, doing that might even fix it.

Comment: From where do you call `chdBoxes`? Have you used the debugger to see if the array gets filled at all? Show also the code where you try to read them

Comment: Right before you set your session, is the data array filled correctly? I really suggest you use List since your array will be greater than what you need.